# podman start stuck on "Waiting for VM..."

Tags: macos, qemu, virtualization, podman

on mac m2 max, I installed podman using `brew intsall podman`, then ran `podman machine init --disk-size 150`, and then `podman start`. It's stuck on "Waiting for VM ...".
I see this error from qemu:
Synchronous Exception at 0x00000000BC562000

Comment: There are some recent [GitHub issues](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%22Waiting+for+VM+...%22) in the Podman project that contain the text `Waiting for VM ...`

Comment: yeah, I switched to qemu version 8.1 and it works ok.

Comment: @RonyTesler can you show, how did you switch versions of qemu?

Comment: I followed this: https://nelson.cloud/how-to-install-older-versions-of-homebrew-packages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move to qemu version 8.1 until there's a fix.
how to install version 8.1: [nelson.cloud/how-to-install-older-versions-of-homebrew-packages](https://nelson.cloud/how-to-install-older-versions-of-homebrew-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the qemu helped me start the podman machine again.

`> brew upgrade qemu`

More details can be found in the github issue below -

https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/20776